# Will the following create any zombie process?

Tags: c, operating-system, system-calls

```c
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    fork();
    fork();
    fork();
    exit(0);
}
```

Can this about code create a **Zombie** process? if yes how and how many? It would be great if you could elaborate. Also can see process becoming a zombie using `ps aux | grep a.out`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that won't create any zombie processes. When a process becomes orphaned (because its parent called `exit`, for example), `init` adopts it, and `init` quickly reaps any of its children that die.